# Unlimited sides to dice in simulator

Tags: python, random, simulator, dice

I am new to python and programming in general. I am trying to create a dice simulator that will allow the user the choose how many sides the dice has and how many times to roll the dice. Then the program is supposed to keep track of how many times each number comes up and display the result.

I have gotten this far, where the random number generator will generate a random number for each roll. But i can't figure out how to track the number of times each number comes up and display that. Please help:

```
# dice simple

import random


x = input ("How many sides does you dice have?")
y = input ("How many times do you want to roll?")



for i in range (y):
    z = random.randint (1, x)
```

Comment: `y` and `x` are strings you need to convert them to ints `x = int(x)`

Comment: @jramirez unless this is Python 2.x, in which case the advice is to use `raw_input` and then do that...

Comment: Hello, yes I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
import sys
from random import randint

# Python 2/3 compatibility
if sys.hexversion >= 0x3000000:
    inp = input
    rng = range
else:
    inp = raw_input
    rng = xrange

def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(inp(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def main():
    sides = get_int("How many sides does your die have? ")
    times = get_int("How many times do you want to roll? ")
    results = Counter(randint(1, sides) for roll in rng(times))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks Hugh, can you please explain what the following does?             if __name__=="__main__":
    main()

Comment: @user3058598: if you run the .py file directly, it calls `main()`; if you load it as a module, it doesn't. It's pretty much the standard way to structure a Python program.

Answer (score 2):

`defaultdict` fits nicely:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
d[1] += 1
d[6] += 1
d[1] += 1

print(d)
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 2, 6: 1})
```

Comment: Since you're teaching a newby, I would recommend using the PEP-8 recommended formatting.  (My understanding/interpretation of) PEP8 recommends no spaces between []s and ()s (i.e. d[ 1 ] -> d[1]) and using a space between the '+=' and the '1' (+=1 -> += 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
# dice simple

import random


x = input ("How many sides does you dice have?")
y = input ("How many times do you want to roll?")


for i in range (y):
    z = random.randint (1, x)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; you just copied the code the OP. The same one he was struggling with.