# advanced dice roll simulator w/ histogram in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram, dice

I'm writing a program that asks the user for the number of dice, and the number of sides on the dice. It calculates how many times each value was rolled, then puts them in a list. I must then print the list along with the percentage, and a histogram of the values, and the histogram has a max value of 80, with everything based around that. I don't know why, but i'm having a tough time. This is my code thus far:

```
import random

def histogram(L):
    mx = max(L)
    scale = 80/mx
    for num in L:
        print("#"*int(num*scale))

def main():
    rolls = int(input("How many times do you want to roll the dice?"))
    sides = int(input("How many sides on the dice?"))
    L = []
    for i in range(rolls+1):
        L.append(random.randrange(1,sides+1))

    histogram(L)

main()
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You're starting with a list containing each dice roll. You need to convert that list to some sort of structure containing a count for each possible roll value, before you pass it to `Histogram`. There was such a question earlier today, search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Start with [Unlimited sides to dice in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335617/unlimited-sides-to-dice-in-simulator/20335858#20335858)

then

```
def bar(value, scale):
    print('{} {}'.format('#'*int(value*scale + 0.5), value))

def histogram(results, maxbar=76, displayfn=bar):
    # find the histogram domain
    values = list(results.keys())
    lo, hi = min(values), max(values)
    # find the data range
    scale = maxbar / float(max(results.values()))
    # output the results
    for val in rng(lo, hi+1):
        bar(results[val], scale)
```